# How to detect if Touch input intersects uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, touch

Can't seem to find an answer to this one anywhere.

My game starts when the user touches the screen, there is a path that the finger must stay within, if it touches/intersects the edges then I want it to run the method [self gameover].

The edge will be a UIImageView.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have overridden the touches moved event. check either the user touch intersects your image view like below.

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point =[touch locationInView:self.view]; 
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, point))
    {
        //Intersects
          [self gameOver];
    }
}
```